# How to subscribe to observable in observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS and trying to subscribe to an `observable` that is in an `observableArray` that is in an `observableArray`. So my viewModel looks like this...

```
function viewModel() {
    // private properties
    var self = this;

    // public properties
    self.movies = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

    // subscriptions
    self.movies.UserMovies.Rating.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
    });
}
```

The `movies` observableArray would look like this once populated from the mapping plugin...

```
[{
    Id: 1,
    Title: 'Movie1',
    Year: 2010,
    UserMovies: [{ Id: 11, Rating: 3.5, IsWatched: true }]
},{
    Id: 2,
    Title: 'Movie2',
    Year: 2010,
    UserMovies: [{ Id: 4, Rating: 4, IsWatched: true }]
}]
```

I'm trying to set up a subscription to UserMovies.Rating but, from my above viewModel getting the error message

> TypeError: self.movies.UserMovies is undefined

**How would I got about setting up a subscription to `UserMovies.Rating` when it is populated from the mapping plugin?**

Comment: You can use the latest version of this plugin if you want in depth subscription to arrays: https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knockout does not provide the granularity for knowing which items changed in an array, just that *something* changed. You will need to loop trough the array each time an item is added or removed.

The `foreach` binding (via `ko.utils.compareArrays`) actually calculates the minimum number of operations to transform one array into another one, so that DOM-elements does not need to be recreated.

Using `ko.utils.compareArrays`, I was able to create a method that subscribes to array changes at an item level. Leveraging this, I could write a `select` method that manages the subscriptions.

http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/s9M4z/

With the new `select` method, you could do this pretty concisely:

```
// Subscribe to items added to the array. The returned 'subscription' will be
// disposed of, when the item is later removed.
viewModel.movies.select(function (movie) {

    // Return the subscription. Same as above.
    return movie.UserMovies.select(function (userMovie) {

        // Subscribe to a non-array. The callback will receive the updated value,
        // instead of the an added item.
        return userMovie.Rating.select(function (rating) {

            // Executed each time a rating is updated.
            console.log(movie.Id(), userMovie.Id(), rating);
        });
    });
});
```

It handles additions, updates, and deletions as expected.

Comment: @bflemi3 I wasn't satisfied with the previous version, since it couldn't handle deletions. This one is more robust.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to loop through your movies and subscribe to each one's rating property:

```
$.each(self.movies(), function(i, movie) { 
     movie.Rating.subscribe(function(newRatingValue){  /* ... */ }) 
});
```

Of course the donwside here is that you'll also have to subscribe to the array itself, for situations in which you add new movies to the array, and then manually subscribe to changes in *their* rating value as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of subscribe to your properties in this fashion:

```
   var UserMovies = function (data) {
        this.Id = ko.observable();
        this.Rating = ko.observable();
        this.IsWatched = ko.observable();
        this.update(data);
    }

    ko.utils.extend(UserMovies.prototype, {
        update: function (data) {
            this.Id(data.Id || "");
            this.Rating(data.Rating || "");
            this.Rating.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
            });
            this.IsWatched(data.IsWatched || "");
        }
    });
```

I'm not sure what you might be able to do or not do from subscribing to things inside of your object, but this does work. I'm also not sure if each subscription will be unique, or if one Rating change will set off all UserMovies ratings subscriptions. I have not tested that. I've only used this in single objects and not arrays of objects.